# Getting error when mouse hover an element

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Getting error when mouse hover an element with below code in selenium:

```
public void our_medicines(String locatorType, String value) {
 try {
  By locator;
  locator = locatorValue(locatorType, value);
  Actions action = new Actions(driver);
  WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
  WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(locator));
  action.moveToElement(element).click().build().perform();
 } catch (Exception e) {
  System.err.format("no such element to mousehover" + e);
 }
}
```

This is my `locatorValue` method:

```
public By locatorValue(String locatorTpye, String value) {
 By by;
 switch (locatorTpye) {
  case "id":
   by = By.id(value);
   break;
  case "name":
   by = By.name(value);
   break;
  case "xpath":
   by = By.xpath(value);
   break;
  case "css":
   by = By.cssSelector(value);
   break;
  case "linkText":
   by = By.linkText(value);
   break;
  case "partialLinkText":
   by = By.partialLinkText(value);
   break;
  case "className":
   by = By.className(value);
   break;
  default:
   by = null;
   break;
 }
 return by;
}
```

Comment: Show us your `locatorValue` method.

Comment: As a side note, if you are trying to only hover, remove ".click()" from the action statement.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so the problem I found with your locatorValue method was that it could not handle unspecified locators in this block

```
default: by = null;
 break;
 }
 return by; }
```

I added something simple just to deal with that, but you can tune it however you want

```
default: throw new Exception("Locator type not defined");
}
return by; }
```

Make sure the locatorType parameter being passed to `public void our_medicines`is a valid Locator type.